# Persistence in time series

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, terminology

Could someone tell me what the term 'persistence' mean in time series analysis? It's regarding econometrics and applied regression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Roughly speaking, the term *persistence* in time series context is often related to the notion of *memory* properties of time series. To put it another way, you have a persistent time series process if the effect of infinitesimally (very) small shock will be influencing the future predictions of your time series for a very long time. Thus the longer the time of influence the longer is the memory and the extremely persistence. You may consider an integrated process I(1) as an example of highly persistent process (information that comes from the shocks never dies out). Though fractionally integrated (ARFIMA) processes would be more interesting examples of persistent processes. Probably it would be useful to read about *Measuring Conditional Persistence in Time Series* in G.Kapetanios article.

Comment: In graduate level textbooks the persistence usually is the synonym of unit root.

Comment: The link to the article seems to be down. can you pls update

Comment: I would appreciate if you could answer this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388968/how-to-do-psm-with-panel-data-using-panelmatch Thanks @DmitrijCelov

Answer (score 1):

A persistent series is one where the value of the variable at a certain date is closely related to the previous value. The two basic measures of persistence are the autocovariance and the autocorrelation coefficient.