# Can time series data have both unit root and structural break?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity, unit-root, structural-change

My data rejects unit root, but shows structural break, is this possible?

Comment: Your *data* doesn't reject anything, it's just numbers. I assume you applied some test. Wouldn't a structural break invalidate the test assumptions? But yes, you can write models that have a unit root *and* a structural break, so data could have both.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already answered about the wrong idea of hypothesis testing. Regarding your question : yes it is possible. 
Take for example this time series. It is the price series of a stock of the S&P 500 (therefore, real data) in a time span of more than 10 years. As you can see the series presents what seems to be a structural change. The ADF, with constant and constant plus trend, gives a p-value respectively of 0.003629 and 0.01257, therefore we can reject the null hypothesis of a unit root (if we assume a level of significance of 5%). Since we suspect the presence of a break, I run also a unit root test with an unknown breakpoint, which computed p-value is equal to 0.0239, once again we can reject the null of a unit root.

The second figure shows an OLS-based CUSUM test with alternative boundaries and alfa equals to 0.05 plotted with the R package "*strucchange*", which shows you the contemporaneous precence of a break.

[image: price series]

[image: CUSUM]

Answer (score 3):

The two older answers already give you a good sense, yet I would like to add some points about the nature of unit-roots and unit root testing.

Please refer to the following question in order

[What is the difference between a stationary test and a unit root test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stationary-test-and-a-unit-root-test/235916#235916)

Here is the part of my answer which matters for you:

> **How unit-root test and stationarity-test complement each other**
>   If you have a time series data set how it usually appears in econometric time series I propose you should apply both a Unit root test: (Augmented) Dickey Fuller or Phillips-Perron depending on the structure of the underlying data and a KPSS test.
>
> **Case 1** Unit root test: you can’t reject $H_0$; KPSS test: reject $H_0$. Both imply that series has unit root.
>
> **Case 2** Unit root test: Reject $H_0$. KPSS test: don`t reject $H_0$. Both imply that series is stationary.
>
> **Case 3** If we can’t reject both test: data give not enough observations.
>
> **Case 4** Reject unit root, reject stationarity: both hypothesis are component hypothesis – heteroskedasticity in series may make a big difference; if there is structural break it will affect inference.
>
> **Power problem:** if there is small random walk component (small variance $σ^2$ u ), we can’t reject unit root and can’t reject stationarity.

Your data does not reject a unit root or reject stationarity. Certain hypothesis tests reject a unit root or reject stationarity. Maybe you can go deeper into hypothesis testing for unit roots and stationarity and there won't be any contradiction between unit roots and stationarity anymore.

---

---

---

If your data has a structural break it means that a pattern in the data "breaks" exactly one time. If your data has a unit root it means that a pattern in the data "breaks" in every time period. However there are various possibilities between "one break" and a "break in every time period". The paper [Multiple Trend Breaks And The Unit-Root Hypothesis](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/tprrestat/v_3a79_3ay_3a1997_3ai_3a2_3ap_3a212-218.htm) by Lumsdaine and Papell examines the possibility of having more than one structural break in the data. They also show a test for testing for more than one structural break.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. Nothing restricts the following DGP to exist:

$$ y_t = 
\begin{cases}
    c,& \text{if } t = 0 \\
    y_{t-1} + e_t,& \text{if } 0 < t < t_1\\
    -y_{t-1} + e_t,& \text{if } t_1 \leq t
\end{cases}
$$

where $e_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

An implementation in `R`:

```
remove(list = ls())

set.seed(1)
i <- 1
n1 <- 50
n2 <- 100
y <- seq(10, 10, length.out=n2)
e <- rnorm(n2,0,6)

for(i in 2:n1){
  y[i] <- y[i - 1] + e[i]
}

for(j in n1:n2){
  y[j] <- -y[j - 1] + e[j]
}

plot(y, type="o")

library(tseries)
adf.test(y)
```

The graph is

[image]

and the test result is:

```
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  y
Dickey-Fuller = -2.564, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.343
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Your *data* doesn't reject anything, it's just numbers. I assume you applied some test. Wouldn't a structural break invalidate the test assumptions? But yes, you can write models that have a unit root *and* a structural break, so data could have both. – Glen_b