# Do I want a p-value of 1?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, equivalence

I am doing a biology experiment for the first time, and even though the teacher did not require me to do this, I calculated the p-values for the data on my experiment.

They all are above 0.25. From what I have read online, this is beyond acceptable.

**However** the goal of my biology experiment is to prove that if I water my plants 35% less there should be no statistical difference between my plants and the pants that are watered as normal.

Wouldn't it, in this case, mean that the data that I obtained from watering my plants less is very similar to the data from the controlled sample and therefore we would want a p value that is close to 1?

Comment: Could you try describing your procedure in greater detail, step-by-step? How did you calculate the p-value? What exactly is the hypothesis that you are trying to test? You want to see if there is a difference in plant's growth given the experimental condition, where for one of the conditions you watered them less?

Comment: I used excel's T-Test; selected a sample size of 10 data points for 2 arrays, set it to 2 tails and of type 2. Yes, I basically want to confirm that watering them less does not have a significant impact on the data. I apologize if I sound so lost, like I said, I only learnt about this a couple hours ago. I will gladly provide any other info that might be of help!

Comment: No statistics is better than bad statistics. You have to be very very careful with statistics - the assumptions behind the tests, how your data was collected, how the results can be interpreted. Do not just apply tests that sound like they should fit your problem - the results are likely to be misleading!

Comment: Consider, for example, what it is exactly that you want to test. "No statistical difference" - what exactly do you mean by that? If you gathered a billion samples watered at 100%, and a billion samples at 65%, and even if you managed to keep all other variables perfectly controlled, I bet that you would find a possibly very very tiny, but nonetheless significant (in the sense that it is real, reproducible and caused by the difference in watering) difference between the two samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comment you said that

> Yes, I basically want to confirm that watering them less does not have a significant impact on the data.

In such case, you want to run an [equivalence](/questions/tagged/equivalence) test, for example two one-sided tests (see questions tagged as [tost](/questions/tagged/tost)), as standard hypothesis test won't work for such scenario. You can find more details in [Why do statisticians say a non-significant result means "you can't reject the null" as opposed to accepting the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85903/why-do-statisticians-say-a-non-significant-result-means-you-cant-reject-the-nu), [Does failure to reject the null in Neyman-Pearson approach mean that one should "accept" it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125541/does-failure-to-reject-the-null-in-neyman-pearson-approach-mean-that-one-should), and [Is it possible to prove a null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6225/is-it-possible-to-prove-a-null-hypothesis), to give few examples of related threads. You should start with reading the threads, especially the last one seems to answer your question.

Comment: thank you so much - this is exactly what I needed!