# Accepting vs failing to accept the null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

In [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6859766/) paper the authors state the following regarding a null hypothesis significance test:

> If P-value < critical value, reject null hypothesis and accept the
> alternative hypothesis (difference detected). If P-value > critical
> value, accept null hypothesis (no difference is detected)

Have the authors made a mistake by saying 'accept the null'? I initially thought so but then I noticed in the abstract they state:

> P value is condemned by one school of thought who claims that focusing
> more on P value undermines the generalizability and reproducibility of
> research.

So they are clearly aware of the issues with p-values. So why do they then say 'accept the null' instead of 'fail to reject the null'? Maybe its just a convention to say 'accept the null' even if one is aware that what we are really doing is failing to reject the null?

Comment: A possible reason is because they do not know about tests for equivalence, such as [TOST](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info).

Comment: Some related threads: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60670/accept-null-hypothesis-or-fail-to-reject-the-null-hypothesis), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85903/why-do-statisticians-say-a-non-significant-result-means-you-cant-reject-the-nu), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125541/does-failure-to-reject-the-null-in-neyman-pearson-approach-mean-that-one-should)