# Using KPSS test in Python with statsmodels

Tags: python, stationarity, kpss-test

17.7736
17.7736
17.7638
17.7638
17.754
17.754
17.7834
17.7834
17.7834
17.7834
17.7834
17.7834
17.7834
17.7834
17.8324
17.8324
17.8324
17.852
17.9304
17.9304
17.9304
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1362
18.146
18.146
18.1656
18.1754
18.1656
18.1656
18.1656
18.1656
18.1656
18.146
18.1362
18.1362
18.1656
18.1656
18.1656
18.1264
18.1264
18.1264
18.1264
18.1264
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1166
18.1264
18.1264
18.1264
18.1264
18.1

I think this dataset is stationary because the values very near with each other But the surprise when using the Kpss test with this code show that this is not stationary . What is the wrong please I am very confuse

```
# KPSS test
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import kpss
#57358

data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/3800.txt") #, header=0, index_col=0) 

def kpss_test(data, **kw):    
    statistic, p_value, n_lags, critical_values = kpss(data, **kw)
    # Format Output
    print(f'KPSS Statistic: {statistic}')
    print(f'p-value: {p_value}')
   # print(f'num lags: {n_lags}')
    print('Critial Values:')
        
    for key, value in critical_values.items():
        print(f'   {key} : {value}')
                
    print(f'Result: The series is {"not " if p_value < 0.05 else ""}stationary')
 
kpss_test(data)
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you plotted your data? I did. Does it look stationary or “almost stationary” to you?

[image]

Comment: +1 skimming the numbers, it looked like this kind of trend was present.

Comment: @oleva Do these tests have the same null hypothesis?

Comment: @dipetkov.No, it have not!

Comment: Could you check the update please? why this difference? I used another dataset

Comment: @oleva You are focusing on the numbers returned by the tests rather than on what the tests are supposed to test. It will help to start with theory and understand it first.

Comment: Null Hypothesis in(KPSS): Series is trend stationary or series has no unit root. 
Null Hypothesis in (ADF): Series is non-stationary or series has a unit root. Therefore, in ADF If Test statistic < Critical Value and p-value < 0.05 – Reject Null Hypothesis(HO) i.e., time series does not have a unit root, meaning it is stationary.
and in KPSS That is, if p-value is < significance level (say 0.05), then the series is non-stationary. Whereas in ADF test, it would mean the tested series is stationary.

Comment: [What is the difference between a stationary test and a unit root test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stationary-test-and-a-unit-root-test)

Answer (score 3):

I didn’t count how many points you have, but it looks like “a lot” is a good description.

When you have “a lot” of points, hypothesis tests have the [power](/questions/tagged/power) to reject small deviations from the null hypothesis, even deviations so small that they are not of any practical consequence.

This could be what you’re seeing: you’re right that the time series is just about stationary, and the formal test is catching that the time series is not quite exactly stationary.

(I’m not actually convinced that “almost stationary” applies to your time series, but if it does, the test is catching that it is almost stationary, not perfectly stationary.)

Comment: Could you check the update please? why this difference?

Comment: @oleva It’s really not fair to answerers (or future readers) to make the question a moving target. If you have a new question (and yours is totally legitimate), please post it

Comment: Yes, that's right, I modified it, I know it is not permissible, but I asked before and did not get an answer, so I thought I would get the answer here.